# How to get sections from *.config which is not app.config

Tags: c#

my question is how can i get access in c# to a *.config-file which is not the app.config-file. i want to read the sections and values of this example file. I saved that file as system.config in my project. i dont want to parse that xml file manually. is there a option to get the section values directly? Im really new to c# so i hope for your help. thanks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <configuration>
          <configSections>
             <sectionGroup name="common">
               <section name="system"   
                    type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, 
                    Common.Logging" />
             </sectionGroup>
           </configSections>

      <common>
         <system>
           <factoryAdapter type="ConsoleApplication.Log4NetFactoryAdapter, 
            ConsoleApplication" >
            <arg key="configType" value="EXTERNAL" />
            <arg key="configFile" value="log4net.config" />
           </factoryAdapter>
          </system>
       </common>

       <startup>
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" 
            />
       </startup>

       <runtime>
           <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" 
            publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" 
            culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" 
            newVersion="2.0.8.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
          </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>

     </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap {ExeConfigFilename = @"..\YourProjectDir\system.config"};
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationSectionGroup sectionGroup = config.GetSectionGroup("common");
ClientSettingsSection section = (ClientSettingsSection) sectionGroup.Sections.Get("system");
SettingElement setting = section.Settings.Get("your_setting");
```

Comment: thx for the answer. can you tell me now how can i get access on the sections with this solution? just implemented your code and looked in the properties and i got in the properties 22 sections and 11 sectiongroups. i´ll be thankful for your reply.

Comment: edited the answer, also you can create a class for each section like it is done here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i got this error: "
The System.Configuration.DefaultSection object can not be converted to type System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection." .. do you know what we made wrong here?

Comment: try to get the xml within like this var section =
                sectionGroup.Sections.Get("system").SectionInformation.GetRawXml(); and try to deserialize it to your needs

Comment: ok now i can see the following string with the whole section.. but i dont come forward :(              : "<system>\r\n      <factoryAdapter type=\"ConsoleApplication1.Log4NetFactoryAdapter, ConsoleApplication1\">\r\n        <arg key=\"configType\" value=\"EXTERNAL\" />\r\n        <arg key=\"configFile\" value=\"log4net.config\" />\r\n      </factoryAdapter>\r\n    </system>" ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    var sect = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("common") as NameValueCollection;
var value = sect["configType"];
```

Comment: thx huse.ckr. but how can i say the programm to read the system.config file? where i give the path of that file?

Comment: i read the link that you have send to me. but it is not clear to me where i have to give the path of my system.config file. i dont use the standard app.config file. i created a custom file and have to tell the code where to look for it.

Comment: this is the snippet which is relevant? : AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
setup.ConfigurationFile = "<path to your config file>"; ... but how to combine with your code snippet?

Comment: I guess this helps: http://www.bardev.com/2013/11/17/kickstart-c-custom-configuration/

Comment: thx this is a very good article. i read it. but it doesn´t helped me to come ago. cause he used also the app.config file. if i use:      var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName); then i can read the app.config file with the right properties. but i only want to read a custom config file. is there a way to create an object of the configurationmanager which is linked with a custom config file? i dont use the app.config file cause i want have multiple files which i can use in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it. This is my solution:

```
                        string file = fileName;
                        System.Xml.XmlDocument xDoc = new 
                        System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                        NameValueCollection nameValueColl = new 
                        NameValueCollection();

                        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap map = 
                        new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                        map.ExeConfigFilename = file;
                        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                        string xml = config.GetSection(sectionName).SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
                        xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                        System.Xml.XmlNode fatherNode = xDoc.ChildNodes[0];
                        System.Xml.XmlNode fathersChildNode = fatherNode.ChildNodes[0];

                        System.Xml.XmlNode ChildrensChildNode_1 = fathersChildNode.ChildNodes[0];
                        System.Xml.XmlAttribute attribute_1_1 = ChildrensChildNode_1.Attributes[0];
                        System.Xml.XmlAttribute attribute_1_2 = ChildrensChildNode_1.Attributes[1];
                        string attribute_1_key = attribute_1_1.Value;
                        string attribute_1_value = attribute_1_2.Value;

                        System.Xml.XmlNode ChildrensChildNode_2 = fathersChildNode.ChildNodes[1];
                        System.Xml.XmlAttribute attribute_2_1 = ChildrensChildNode_2.Attributes[0];
                        System.Xml.XmlAttribute attribute_2_2 = ChildrensChildNode_2.Attributes[1];
                        string attribute_2_key = attribute_2_1.Value;
                        string attribute_2_value = attribute_2_2.Value;

                        Common.Logging.Configuration.NameValueCollection coll = new Common.Logging.Configuration.NameValueCollection();
                        coll.Add(attribute_1_key, attribute_1_value);
                        coll.Add(attribute_2_key, attribute_2_value);

                        Type type = typeof(Log4NetFactoryAdapter);

                        Common.Logging.Configuration.LogSetting set = new Common.Logging.Configuration.LogSetting(type, coll);
```